SVG CSS drop shadow on hover hiding
What I need is for the SVG to disappear but the drop shadow to remain on hover. What I'm getting is both the SVG and the drop shadow disappearing.


div > svg {
  color: black;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 6px red);
}

div:hover > svg {
  color: transparent;
}
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">
  <g id="ico">
    <path fill="currentColor"
      d="M20.3..." />
  </g>
</svg>

<div>
  <svg style="background-color: transparent;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" role="button">
    <title>A title here</title>
    <use href="#ico"></use>
  </svg>
</div>



How can I change my CSS to get what I need?

On hover you can set filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px red);

you may try color : white instead of color : transparent in div:hover > svg

@Yuvaraj M / @Andrew Foulds: Please ensure a snippet also renders a visible result. Pseudo examples like d="M20.3..." resulting in invalid code are not very helpful. Otherwise keep the abstracted code excerpt.

The problem is that the drop-shadow CSS filter uses the alpha channel of the input under the covers and relies on that being non-zero. When you set its opacity to 0 - the drop-shadow disappears.
So you have to customize the SVG filter that is doing the work under the covers. This turns out to be slightly tricky. You have to set the opacity of the hover color to almost zero - but non zero, and then use the filter to dial it back to normal (the 100 in that color matrix), so that you still have an opaque shape to feed into the dropshadow part of the filter.


div > svg {
  color: black;
  filter: url(#drop-shadow-using-luminance);
}

div:hover > svg {
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.01);
}
<div>
<svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" viewBox="0 0 384 512" height="5em" width="5em" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <filter id="drop-shadow-using-luminance" x="-200%" y="-200%" width="500%" height="500%">

    <feColorMatrix  type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 
                                          0 0 0 0 0 
                                          0 0 0 0 0 
                                          0 0 0 100 0"/>
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="6" result="alphaBlur"/>
    <feFlood flood-color="red"/>
    <feComposite in2="alphaBlur" operator="in"/>
    <feMerge>
     <feMergeNode/>
     <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
    </feMerge>
</filter>
  </defs>
  
  <path d="M0 192H176V0H160C71.6 0 0 71.6 0 160v32zm0 32V352c0 88.4 71.6 160 160 160h64c88.4 0 160-71.6 160-160V224H192 0zm384-32V160C384 71.6 312.4 0 224 0H208V192H384z"></path>  
  </svg>
 </div>




Are you saying that setting the color to transparent is seen as setting the opacity to 0? I only ask because my CSS is changing only color.

I've tried a bunch of things (blending modes, outlines,...) and it seems that its expected that an invisible element not cast a shadow. So I've given up and just added a note to the "documentation".

'transparent' is the same as rgba(0,0,0,0) - which means zero opacity. From the spec: "This keyword can be considered a shorthand for transparent black, rgba(0,0,0,0), which is its computed value."  (I've explained above why a fully transparent shape cannot have an opaque drop-shadow.)

You can try color:white instead of transparent


div > svg {
  color: black;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 6px red);
}

div:hover > svg {
  color: white;
}
<div>
     <svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" viewBox="0 0 384 512" height="5em" width="5em" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M0 192H176V0H160C71.6 0 0 71.6 0 160v32zm0 32V352c0 88.4 71.6 160 160 160h64c88.4 0 160-71.6 160-160V224H192 0zm384-32V160C384 71.6 312.4 0 224 0H208V192H384z"></path>          </svg>
 </div>




Good idea but I can't know the what background the svg happens to be over so white may/will not match the current background color.
